# Livewire pass image property to parent component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have issue passing image property from child to parent component

here's base component which is basically responsible for submitting the data:

```
<div>
 <livewire:child-component />
</div>

<?php

  namespace App\Http\Livewire;

  use Livewire\Component;

  class BaseComponent extends Component
  {

     protected $listeners = [
       'store'
     ];

     public function store($image)
     {
       dd($image); 
       // ['disk' => 'local']
     }

     public function render()
     {
        return view('livewire.base-component');
     }
  }
```

here's child component which is reponsible for validating the uploaded image and pass it to the parent component:

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
        <input type="file" wire:model="image">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class ChildComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $image;

    public function submit()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'image' => 'image'
        ]);

        $this->emitUp('store', $this->image);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.child-component');
    }
}
```

when I dump the image property in the base component I should get and livewire image Object instead I get an array as showed.

**what 's the problem in my code?**

Comment: Are you actually uploading the file in the `ChildComponent`?

Comment: no, I want to upload the file in the parent component

Comment: So your `ChildComponent` just shows an input form for files but does nothing else?

Comment: correct! who can I pass the property image to the parent as livewire image class?

Comment: What's the point? It makes more sense to have the component that has the form input handle the file upload too.

Comment: that's because the parent component persist all data at once. the actual code is bigger than that.

Comment: A better solution would be to perform the upload in the child component and then emit the name of the uploaded file to the parent to be saved. If something goes wrong, just delete the file. It makes no sense to have a component for uploading that doesn't upload.

Comment: well, you're right. I will do just that. you can write an answer so I mark it as the correct one